# Error downloading PDFs from list of links in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 75,000 links that look like this:

```
urls <– c("https://growthlab.cid.harvard.edu/files/growthlab/files/2019-04-cid-wp-350-smart-development-banks.pdf", "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp040.pdf", "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp037.pdf", "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp033.pdf", "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp907.pdf")
```

Not all the links still work (they're from an old database and some will have been moved/ deleted) so I'm trying to use the `try` function to skip errors like so:

```
for (url in urls) try({download.file(url,  destfile="~/Dataset/saved_pdfs")})
```

However, each time the code runs, nothing gets saved. Any idea what's going wrong? Not sure if it matters but I'm using a mac.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a filename as `destile` and not a folder name. Try something like this :

```
url_vec <- unlist(urls)

for (i in seq_along(url_vec)) {
    tryCatch({download.file(url_vec[i],  
       paste0('Downloads/saved_pdfs/file', i, '.pdf'))}, error = function(e) {})
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It's still not downloading the files? Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: What does `head(urls)` look like?

Comment: ```[[1]]
[1] ""

[[2]]
[1] "https://growthlab.cid.harvard.edu/files/growthlab/files/2019-04-cid-wp-350-smart-development-banks.pdf"

[[3]]
[1] "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp040.pdf"

[[4]]
[1] "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp037.pdf"

[[5]]
[1] "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp033.pdf"

[[6]]
[1] "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp028.pdf"```

Comment: @Oliver I think `urls` is a list. Try with `for (url in unlist(urls)) {....` keeping rest of the code same.

Comment: I figured it out! I wrote the destfile wrong and I needed to unlist the urls. Your code works perfectly now. Thanks so much!

Comment: I never use `~`, I thought it is your computer's setting. I use `paste0('Downloads/', basename(url))`

Comment: Hey, just one more question. I like your use of `basename` to shorten the file names but a lot of them are being overwritten (e.g. many end in /document.pdf). Any idea how I can modify your code to prevent overwrites?

Comment: You can create a sequential name, see updated answer. It will create files with name as `file1.pdf`, `file2.pdf` etc.